# Replacing catalytic converter from cut pipe

Tags: honda, catalytic-converter, crv

How would I go about replacing a catalytic converter (2003 Honda CR-V incidentally) when the exhaust pipes were cut as shown in the following pics? Can I mount it somehow without welding it? Most of the "how to"s assume you just have to turn a few nuts.[image]

[image]

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're either going to have to weld something into place or get the entire replacement (new). You won't be able to capture the exhaust gasses to go through the cat otherwise. Even welding would be tough. If you have emissions to pass, it won't pass without being sealed, either.

Comment: What does the entire replacement comprise? You can send a link. Is it a huge job that can't be done in the home garage?

Comment: Hit me up in [The Pitstop](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/340/the-pitstop) which is the site's chat room, as we would have a greater ability to talk there.